# Bootstrap3 select box shows two boxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am presenting data options in a `<select>` box on a Bootstrap site/form.  Below is the code:

```
// Status
echo '<label for="data_status" class="col-md-2 control-label">Status</label>';
echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
echo '<select class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" id="data_status">';   
    echo '<option value="1">Active</option>';           
    echo '<option value="2">Maint</option>';            
    echo '<option value="3">Storage</option>';          
    echo '<option value="4">Decomm</option>';           
    echo '<option value="5">Reclaim</option>';  
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';  // End Status
```

I have tried multiple approaches, including `<ul>/<li>` structures, the [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin, etc.

This data is a set list that is being set by an AJAX query, given the current status of the object in the database.  That part works fine.

My problem is that, in the GUI, there are two boxes in the form.  One is a text box that holds the selected data, right below it is the dropdown with the caret character.  [See Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZU0i.jpg)

This appears to either be missing CSS or missing javascript to hide the dropdown menu itself?  Below is my header file sections for includes and CSS.

```
    <!-- Libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/formValidation/formValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/formValidation/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.slate.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/bootstrap/css/dashboard.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/formValidation.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

Any ideas on why this dropdown/select is not behaving correctly, and is showing two boxes instead of the expected one?

Comment: Can you check if there is any code conflict with **bootstrap-select**?

Comment: This was happening before I tried bootstrap-select, but removing the Javascript and CSS links do not affect the double-boxes, no.

Comment: Seriously? Possibly PHP script is duplicating the select box?

Comment: I am not sure how that can be.  The php code is above, and a search will show that the id is used nowhere else on the page (aside from the ajax javascript above).

Comment: Also, @AnwarHussain, if you look at the screenshot, the first box is a text box and the second box has the dropdown caret decoration in it.  As I said, this seems to be something in the CSS/code of jQuery somehow.

Comment: This is solved.  I discovered that removing the library for jquery-mobile solved the issue.

Comment: Great. I am glad that you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

Was including jquery-mobile libraries.  Removed that from the page and it is working.